# Bought a scam token, trying to understand what part of the code should I check next time to prevent that

Tags: solidity, erc-20, contract-design, scam

Contract code - https://etherscan.io/token/0x67bcd18a484a88f073097a18b0462eb7c44d3178#code
Ownership renounce at 08:17 UTC https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8736e02afdd1ba7653159cea9d9837f0033c5b815ae7bc3609ef3180c319842a
Sell trade happening 20 minutes later at 08:40 UTC
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x017e189d7330d852deff0c097223d49cc419d1edab13ff7ea28ad00b7a3c4de9
After that there were no trades, nor it was allowed as I tried.

I read the other questions related to the ERC-20 contract scams, but didn't find my answers.

1. How did dev prevent sells after renouncing the ownership?
2. Why did some people (non-dev) were able to sell their coins?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's one rule that always worked for me: Never deploy a contract that you cannot explain how it works to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The code of every ERC20 token looks almost the same. You can not determine fake tokens with code.
Anyone can make token and pools. pools are used to put some value of ERC20 tokens. If peoples trust the token like USDT, it have value even after pool created by ERC20 token creator is fulfilled, else the token have no value.

To determine which token is fake, and which to exchange for other crypto/money, you should go though who created the token, where it is used, and social media/website of that token, etc.

You should trust the token if you see something is there in token. and there is high probability that new token will have 0 value after 2 days. Even bitcoin had chances to have 0 value, and it had almost 0 value once.

so, trust token but not trust bliendly or put all money on new tokens.